# Spring Data REST/JPA - Update OneToMany collection with composite key

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

Using Spring Data REST and Spring Data JPA, I want to update a child entity collection on an aggregate root. As an example to demonstrate, let's say I have a `Post` entity that has a one-to-many relationship with the `Comment` entity. `Post` has its own Spring Data repository; `Comment` does not because it is only accessed through `Post`.

The nasty twist is that `Comment` has a composite key including the foreign key to `Post` due to existing database design. Consequently, I could not find a way to have the foreign key be part of the composite key in `Comment` without a bidirectional relationship, even though I have no need for a bidirectional relationship.

The classes look like the following with Lombok annotations:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Comment> comments = new HashSet<>();

    private String title;
}
```

And the Comment:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(Comment.CommentPk.class)
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "post")
@ToString(exclude = "post")
public class Comment {

    @Id
    private long id;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Post post;

    private String content;

    @Data
    static class CommentPk implements Serializable {
        private long id;

        private Post post;
    }
}
```

And the repository:

```
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Long> {
}
```

If I try to create a `Post` with a `Comment`, an exception will occur that `POST_ID` cannot be NULL. In other words, it is missing the back-reference to the parent `Post` in the `Comment` it is trying to persist.

This can be solved by adding a `@PrePersist` method to `Post` that maintains this back-reference:

```
@PrePersist
private void maintainParentBackreference() {
    for (Comment comment : this.comments) {
        comment.setPost(this);
    }
}
```

The above works fine when creating a new `Post`, but it does not help when trying to add a `Comment` to an existing `Post` (e.g. with a PUT request) because the following error will occur when trying to insert the Comment:

```
NULL not allowed for column "POST_ID"; SQL statement:
insert into comment (content, id, post_id) values (?, ?, ?) [23502-193]
```

To recap, the steps to reproduce are:

1. POST a `Post` with no `Comment`s
2. PUT to the created `Post` **with** a `Comment`

What is the simplest way I can achieve being able to update/add `Comment`s to an existing `Post` using Spring Data REST?

A sample project that demonstrates this can be found here: https://github.com/shakuzen/aggregate-child-update-sample/tree/composite-key

This particular setup is in the `composite-key` branch of the repository. To reproduce the above described failure with this code, you can follow the manual reproduction steps in the README or run the integration test `AggregateCompositeKeyUpdateTests.canAddCommentWithPut`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should not be using the `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate` callbacks to manage these back-references because their invocation is often dependent on whether the state of `Post` is actually being manipulated or not.

Instead, these relationships should be something which you're manipulating as part of some domain-specific code that your controller or some business service calls.  I often prefer to abstract these types of relationships behind a more Domain Driven Design approach:

```
public class Post {
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "Post", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, ...)
  private Set<Comment> comments;

  // Allows access to the getter, but it protects the internal collection
  // from manipulation from the outside, forcing users to use the DDD methods.
  public Set<Comment> getComments() {
     return Collections.unmodifiableSet( comments );
  }

  // Do not expose the setter because we want to control adding/removing
  // of comments through a more DDD style.
  private void setComments(Set<Comment> comments) {
     this.comments = comments;
  }

  public void addComment(Comment comment) {
    if ( this.comments == null ) {
      this.comments = new HashSet<Comment>();
    }
    this.comments.add( comment );
    comment.setPost( this );
  }

  public void removeComment(Comment comment) {
    if ( this.comments != null ) {
      for ( Iterator<Comment> i = comments.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
        final Comment postComment = i.next();
        if ( postComment.equals( comment ) ) {
          // uses #getCompositeId() equality
          iterator.remove();
          comment.setPost( null );
          return;
        }
      }
    }
    throw new InvalidArgumentException( "Comment not associated with post" );
  }
```

As you see from the code, users of the `Post` entity object are forced to use `#addComment` and `#removeComment` if they wish to manipulate the associated comments.  These methods make sure that the back-reference is set correctly.

```
final Comment comment = new Comment();
// set values on comment
final Post post = entityManager.find( Post.class, postId );
post.addComment( comment );
entityManager.merge( post );
```

**UPDATE - Spring Data REST Solution**

In order to have Spring Data REST apply this logic directly, you can either write a listener or a callback class.

An example of a listener would be:

```
public class BeforeSavePostEventListener extends AbstractRepositoryEventListener {
  @Override
  public void onBeforeSave(Object entity) {
    // logic to do by inspecting entity before repository saves it.
  }
}
```

An example of an annotated handler would be:

```
@RepositoryEventHandler 
public class PostEventHandler {
  @HandleBeforeSave
  public void handlePostSave(Post p) {
  }
  @HandleBeforeSave
  public void handleCommentSave(Comment c) {
  } 
}
```

Next you just need to make sure that this bean is picked up by either specifying one of the various `@Component` stereotypes through scanning or you need to specify it as a `@Bean` in a configuration class.

The biggest difference between the two approaches is that the second is type-safe and the entity-type is determined by the first argument to the various annotated methods.

You can find more details on this [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.6.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#events).

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth response. I would be happy to do as you suggest if I could easily have Spring Data REST use those methods when handling the corresponding HTTP requests, but I'm not sure how to best make that happen.

Comment: Added information about how to integrate my idea with Spring Data REST using a listener or annotated handler callbacks.

Comment: But doesn't it seem cleaner to just use the PrePersist/PreUpdate annotations, since that covers both cases (Spring Data Rest and calling add/remove methods)?

Comment: @EricTurley That's debatable.  I find it cleaner to assign the association in the business code that is about to invoke `save`/`update` or `persist`/`merge` rather than decouple it and invoke it during some callback.  In short, if I can assign other values, there is no reason I shouldn't be able to do exactly that for associations so that prior to calling into the `Session` or `EntityManager`, the entity state is complete.  What happens when you need to use a stateless session and those callbacks are no longer invoked?  The cleanest solution is to simply populate the entity together.